# Solution to 3D matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d

In `AX = B`, if `A` is 3D(n×n×i) matrix and `B` is 3D(1×n×i) matrix but more like a single row in 3D, then what will be the dimension of `X`? and How to solve this in `matlab`?

Comment: Matrix inverses are only defined for 2D matrices.  It is undefined for 3D matrices.  If you give more insight into the exact problem you want to solve, then we'd/I'd be more inclined to help you.

Comment: By 'a single row in 3D' do you mean j = 1?

Comment: If you are working with N-D matrices, i suggest that you formulate your problem with indices (Einstein-like notation for tensors): Ax=b--> A_i_j x_j = b_i. This way we can understand more easily what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are describing a set of `i` systems of equations with `n` equations in `n` unknowns for each system. A way to solve this would be

```
 X = zeros( n, ii ); %//pre-allocate
 for jj=1:ii
     X(:,ii) = A(:,:,jj) \ squeeze(B(1,:,jj));
 end
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct for the full 3D system, there are also n nxj systems of equation in the third dimension

Comment: @Kostya I assumed `X` is of size `n`x`ii`, in that case the system of equations are decoupled of each other. If `X` is only `n`x1 then there is a coupling between the systems and the matrix needs to be re-arranged differently to solve the over constraint system.